# keeping Object Data after passing it to a strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC 3 site, from my Controller out of the Edit Action I pass a Object (a class which is also mapped by nhibernate)

After editing and clicking save i pass it to the [HTTPPost] decoraded Method but and all properties are correct, excerpt the "id" property it hat a guid value equivalent to NULL (00000000-0000-000...).

Is there a problem using the Domain Model to strongly type my Views? May the problem be that Id has:

`{get; private set;}`

???

Thanks in advance.

Here The Code:

My View:

```
'@model fnh.DataModel.Kunde

@{
    View.Title = "EditKunde";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>EditKunde</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model._id)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model._KdNr);

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model._Name)
  `enter code here`      </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model._Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

'

My Controller Actions:

'       public ActionResult EditKunde(Guid id)
        {
            return View(_kunden.GetKundeById(id));
        }

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditKunde(Kunde kunde)
    {
        Ansprechpartner anp = new Ansprechpartner();
        anp._Name = "JustATry";
        kunde._Ansprechpartner.Add(anp);
     `enter code here`   _kunden.EditKunde(kunde);
        return View();
    }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you adding the Id property to your form (maybe as a `hidden` field)?

It would be useful if you post the Action code (for both Edit Actions), and the View.

Comment: Seems that the DefaultModelBinder won't bind to a property whose setter is private or protected. Try changing it to `{get; set;}`. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Yes that's it... but there should be some solution, or should I "duplicate" my Domain and wrap the Data to a own ViewModel (which would seem duplicate code)??? Any Idea or Tip?

Comment: I usually use one ViewModel per view, and map it to the corresponding Domain classes using AutoMapper, and it has worked well.
At first I wasn't so convinced to do so, but then I realized that doing so gives you more freedom to choose your View shape.

Comment: You can get some inspiration from Jimmy Bogard's blog: [How we do MVC – View models](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/06/29/how-we-do-mvc-view-models.aspx)